# HDD Dying or still good?

Tags: hard-drive

[image: CrystalDisk Info]

Is my hdd still good? because when am playing some games my pc crashes BSOD(Critical Process Died , Kernel Data Inpage)

Comment: Some years ago I had a similar problem. It would only BSOD only while playing games and I could play for quite a while before it would happen. I thought it was my SSD. It ended up being a bad SATA controller on my motherboard. SSD SMART scan passed, Crystal Disk said all was good, RAM tests passed, CPU tests passed, etc. It took me 2 months to figure that out it was the SATA controller. Once I replaced the motherboard, all was good. So this may be something to consider if all other tests you run end up passing.

Comment: From an administrative command prompt run **chkdsk /r e:**  It will warn you it will have to dismount the filesystem, and ask if you want to proceed.  Say **Y**.  It may also tell you need to reboot, agree.  You will need to manually reboot.  It will probably take 4+ hours to complete, plan accordingly.  Maybe overnight?

Answer (score 3):

Your hard drive is fine.

Its also somewhat unlikely that a bad hard disk would directly cause a BSOD.  (But if there is data corruption in an executable that might be the cause - although it would be pretty far down my list of things).  The Write error rate is 0 as is the seek error rate and reallocated event count - so again, these point AWAY from this being a hdd issue.

I would run a CPU burn in and memory burn in test as those are both much more likely candidates for where the issue lies then the hard dis.